# MySQL Check for 3 or more consecutive (specific) entries

Tags: mysql, database

I have a following table:

```
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field      | Type                                                                              |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned                                                                  |
| type       | enum('REGISTER','ACTIVATE','LOGIN_SUCCESS','LOGIN_FAIL','LOGOUT','LOCK','UNLOCK') |
| user_id    | int(10) unsigned                                                                  |
| mod_id     | int(10) unsigned                                                                  |
| date       | timestamp                                                                         |
| ip         | int(10) unsigned                                                                  |
| user_agent | text                                                                              |
+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I am trying to determine, in the simplest possible way (preferably just using MySQL), if there are 3 or more consecutive records with `type = LOGIN_FAIL` since the last `type = LOGIN_SUCCESS` or since start of the table.

For example

```
+----+---------------+---------+--------+---------------------+----+------------+
| id | type          | user_id | mod_id | date                | ip | user_agent |
+----+---------------+---------+--------+---------------------+----+------------+
|  6 | LOGIN_SUCCESS |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
|  7 | LOGIN_FAIL    |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
|  8 | LOGIN_FAIL    |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
|  9 | LOGIN_FAIL    |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
+----+---------------+---------+--------+---------------------+----+------------+
```

would return `TRUE` while

```
+----+---------------+---------+--------+---------------------+----+------------+
| id | type          | user_id | mod_id | date                | ip | user_agent |
+----+---------------+---------+--------+---------------------+----+------------+
|  6 | LOGIN_FAIL    |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
|  7 | LOGIN_FAIL    |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
|  8 | LOGIN_SUCCESS |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
|  9 | LOGIN_FAIL    |       3 |   NULL | 2012-07-21 14:08:32 |  0 | agent      |
+----+---------------+---------+--------+---------------------+----+------------+
```

would return `FALSE`. Is it possible to do this with a simple query or do I need to implement this check in some script language?

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that this query would have to be limited to a certain user_id but I assume this wouldn't be a problem.

Otherwise, or even better, would it be possible to count how much records fit this criteria (i.e. how many consecutive `type = LOGIN_FAILED` records exist since last `type=LOGIN_SUCCESS`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` 
WHERE 
    id > 
        (IFNULL(
            (SELECT id 
            FROM `table` 
            WHERE `type`='LOGIN_SUCCESS' 
            ORDER BY id DESC 
            LIMIT 1),0
        )
    AND `type`='LOGIN_FAIL'
```

Will get the amount of fails since last success.

Comment: Thanks this nearly fixes the problem :) There's just one small issue when there are no `LOGIN_SUCCESS` in the table at all. In which case it always returns 0. Is there a possible fix for this?

Comment: Don't worry I figure it out :) Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(a.id)>=3, TRUE, FALSE) AS fresult FROM last_login AS a, 
(
        SELECT COUNT( b.id ) AS cnt, MAX( b.id ) AS maxid FROM last_login AS b 
        WHERE b.login_type =  'LOGIN_SUCCESS' 
) AS c  

WHERE a.id>c.maxid OR c.cnt=0
GROUP BY a.login_type
```